# My password didn't pass valid authentication in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I'm trying to find and fix the error but can't.

I enter my account and password on the login form.

When I enter the correct username and whether I enter the wrong password or the correct password, everything can be logged in

```
    public function dangnhap(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Tài khoản', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Mật khẩu', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() ==TRUE){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            if($this->Mcustomer->customer_login($username, $password)!=FALSE){
                $row = $this->Mcustomer->customer_login($username, $password);
                $this->session->set_userdata('sessionKhachHang',$row);
                $this->session->set_userdata('id',$row['id']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('email',$row['email']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('sessionKhachHang_name',$row['fullname']);
                if($this->session->userdata('cart')){
                    redirect('gio-hang','refresh');
                }else{
                    redirect('thong-tin-khach-hang','refresh');
                }
            }else{
                $this->data['error']='Tài khoản hoặc mật khẩu không chính xác';
                $this->data['title']='Đăng nhập tài khoản';
                $this->data['view']='dangnhap';
                $this->load->view('frontend/layout',$this->data);
            }
        }else{
            $this->data['title']='Smart store - Đăng nhập tài khoản';
            $this->data['view']='dangnhap';
            $this->load->view('frontend/layout',$this->data);
        }     
    }
```

Does anyone have a way? please help me. Thank you so much everyone

Comment: What CI version you are using?

Comment: I saw you have 2 password checks here. The one is CI validation, and the other one is `customer_login` method. Can you show that?

Comment: i use version 3.1.10

Comment: this is my customer_login function

Comment: function customer_login($username, $password){
     $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->or_where('email', $username);
     $this->db->where('password', $password);
     $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        if(count($query->result_array())==1){
         return $query->row_array();
        }else{
         return FALSE;
        } 
    }

Comment: Hmm, I don't work with CI for a long time. But okay, I can guess what you faced. This `$this->db->where('username', $username); $this->db->or_where('email', $username);` should be grouped between `group_start()` and `group_end()`. Beside that, you should include code in your comment to the main post.

You can try my solution and let me know the results. Documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=group_start#query-grouping

Answer (score 0):

First check what your database function is returning with correct password and wrong password by this

```
public function dangnhap(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Tài khoản', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Mật khẩu', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() ==TRUE){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $row = $this->Mcustomer->customer_login($username, $password);
        echo print_r($row)
    }
```

and then first input right password and wrong password and see what it returns. In this way you can check where is the bug.